# Improving weak foot

Tags: football, technique

I'm a able to control and shoot with my right foot. But I'm not at all confident with my left foot. How can I improve my weak foot?

By which I mean to improve my weak foot (in my case left foot) shooting power, accuracy, long lobs.

Comment: This question certainly isn't *too broad*, if anything - it's too narrow. The same passing, shooting and crossing drills you undertake with your right foot need to be undertaken exclusively on your left foot. Focus on short passing first, before moving to longer passes and then shooting.

Comment: I haven't left this as an answer, BTW, as it's primarily opinion and experience-based, and it's unlikely I'll find a good source to back it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone who's only good football skills is good shots with both feet, here's my approach once I decided to improve my weak foot.

Go to a football field, go to the penalty spot and start shooting with your left foot. This will be awkward and you will hit like a 4 year old. That's fine, you will get the feel for it after a while.

Once you're comfortable doing the motion with your left foot, start aiming in the corners of the net and call your shots. Rinse and repeat for the other techniques. The reason you have a weak foot is not because it is weak, it is lack of technique. Once you start to practice using it, you will get better at it.

There's nothing more to it, practice makes perfect.

---

[How to Develop Your Opposite Soccer Foot](http://www.livestrong.com/article/557051-how-to-develop-your-opposite-foot-in-soccer/)
This article from James Holloway on LiveStrong suggests a similar process. It also contains a little more information on how to improve.

> **Shooting Drill**
>
> A simple drill can improve shooting with either foot. A small group of players or coaches is needed. A player begins by running and receiving a pass from a player to the right of the goal, then shooting. Without waiting, she continues running to the left to receive a pass from a player standing by the side of the goal. The first player then shoots with the left foot. The drill should be reversed for players whose dominant foot is the left.
>
> **Patience**
>
> Most people spend their lives favoring their dominant foot. This isn't limited to the soccer field but occurs in all walks of life. As a result, the opposite foot, and the opposite leg in general, are not going to be as strong or coordinated as the dominant leg and foot.

Comment: Ok but can i know how to improve accuracy when going for long pass across the field

Comment: You can use the same principle. Set up a few targets on the group far away, gather 1-2 people and just do long passes. Explain to them you're training your weak foot and don't give up. I used the shot first because it's easier to drill.

Comment: While this answer is primarily opinion-based, it is correct. Training your weak foot is no different to training your strong foot.

Comment: Why can't it be experience-based, which is encouraged on SE? This looks like an answer based on experience...

Comment: It can be, but in general, the best answers combine the answerer's opinion and experience with references to either facts, statistics, or expert opinion. At present, this is a good answer (hence why I upvoted), but could still be improved with the addition of references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42484/discussion-between-s--and-akadian).

Comment: @studro Thanks for the article, I will add it to the answer once I have time to formulate an answer for it.

Answer (score -1):

Play in a side of the field which forces you to use it. Example, if you are a "4" , play as a "3"

Comment: Ok, but what do u mean by 4 and 3??

Comment: right back and left back in english

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football_positions

Comment: if you play as a right back, swapping wings makes a big difference. if you play as a striker, swapping wings doesnt make a big difference because you can still use mainly your right foot playing on the left and being a good striker.

Comment: and if you play in the midfield, at least for me, it used to make a big difference playing more on the left than in the right (I'm right footed)